# Asynchronous ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC the ActionResult class provides the following interface for overriding:

`void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)`

Is there some kind of asynchronous version of this? For instance:

`Task ExecuteResultAsync(ControllerContext context, CancellationToken ct)`